# Failed to create a virtual environment on MacOS with M1 with PyCharm

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, virtualenv, apple-m1

I just bought a new MacBook Pro with M1 Pro
I installed python 3.11 and Pycharm as IDE.
I tried to create a new project using virtualenv but it continues to show an error (see below)...

I tried using Python 3.10, I tried installing it from Homebrew, reinstalling it.. nothing changes...

**Steps to Reproduce**

1. Start a new project.
2. Select VirtualEnv as Interpreter
3. Create

[image: screenshot of creation window]

**What happen**

[image: screenshot of the result]

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to create the virtualenv at `/Users/test`, to which (by default, and unless running as root) you don't have permissions. Try setting the `Location` field to your own home (somewhere under `/Users/antonellobarbone/`).

Comment: Basically, the error message is terrible, though I don't know if PyCharm or whatever it's using to create the virtual environment is to blame.

Comment: @chepner I agree, but the venv path doesn't necessarily have to correlate to the project's path. Even if there will be some other error at a later stage, it is most likely that the current blocker is the lack of permissions to create the new venv at `/Users/test` (as the first screenshot shows).

Comment: Ok putting it under `/Users/antonellobarbone/` worked.
It's ok as "workaround". 

But I'm using PyCharm for years now and I always had the "venv" folder in the project without problems :(

Comment: Try adding a new project, and pay close attention to all the steps you take. If PyCharm still "wants" to create a venv in this location (under `/Users`, and not under the project or your own user), it might be worth reporting this as a bug to JetBrains.

Comment: I tried to create it under `/Users/antonellobarbone/PycharmProjects/<Project Name>/venv` and it worked 

I hope is not a random thing...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating it via command line? If that works, the problem is Pycharm. If not, the problem is either in your base installation or access rights.

Comment: I tried running `python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment` in the SAME directory as PyCharm should create, and it worked no problems!

So it's PyCharm the culprit... as pointed out from @micromoses in the previous answer,  it seems to not have some permissions